# Why does Array#grep throw a syntax error with slashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

The following command works in Ruby 1.9.3p194

```
> %w(a b c).grep(/a/) { |v| v.upcase }
 => ["A"]
```

But if any element in the array has a slash in it, a SyntaxError is thrown:

```
> %w(a/ b c).grep(/a/) { |v| v.upcase }
SyntaxError: (irb):41: syntax error, unexpected tMATCH
%Q/a// =~ /a/
```

I'm assuming I'm using grep incorrectly but the error I'm getting is really confusing. Why does it throw this error, and what is the proper way to find an element in an array based on a regex?

**Update:**

Select gives me what I want, but I'm still curious what grep is for...

```
> %w(a/ b c).select {|v| v =~ /a/ }
=> ["a/"]
```

Comment: Works for me with Ruby 1.8.7. What version are you using?

Comment: Gah it's something in the Rails console that's busting it! irb works fine :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's neither Ruby nor Rails, but a gem called [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/blob/master/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/array.rb#L33-70) which is monkey patching Ruby's grep method. I was using an old version which must have had some bugs. Upgrading to the latest version 1.0.2 fixes the issue.

Comment: I was on version 0.3.2, not sure when the fix was released.

Comment: My goodness. Thanks a lot for pointing out the problematic gem name. I know the grep method is redefined, but can't really figure out where it is redefined.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your error.

At first I thought it was a problem with IRb. It is well known that IRb's parser (which is basically a hodge-podge of unmaintainable `Regexp`s duct-taped together) parses some constructs incorrectly. Also, due to the way IRb works, there are semantic differences between Ruby and IRb, especially with local variables and global methods.

Which is why you should *always* reproduce your error in plain Ruby before posting it here. Or at least try it in Pry, which uses YARV's, Rubinius's or JRuby's parser instead of rolling its own.

But that's not the case here: your first code snippet works just fine, both in plain Ruby and in IRb.

Your *second* code snippet, however, *will* produce the error you encountered, *even* when run in plain Ruby:

```
ruby -e '%Q/a// =~ /a/'
# -e:1: syntax error, unexpected tMATCH
# %Q/a// =~ /a/
#         ^
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem is actually with [awesome_print](https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print/blob/master/lib/awesome_print/core_ext/array.rb#L33-70) abusing Ruby to the fullest extent. I should have removed that gem a long time ago and now I'm paying the price :(

Comment: @Beerlington And use Pry instead!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I've seen pry before, but am more of a debugger guy. Maybe I'll play around with it one of these days.

Comment: @Beerlington You can use both. I use Pry more as a REPL than a debugger.

Comment: For what it's worth, my rails console and irb both start with "1.9.3p194 :002 > " so I actually did think I was in irb.